# DocuSign REST API (Node JS) - Recipients Can Add Fields to Document

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I send envelopes with defined roles. (Sent successfully.)
Everything is correct when I sign with the first recipient, but when I sign with the second, third, and fourth recipients, the defined fields do not appear.

I define the envelope with data from my DB with 4 roles (Candidato, Testigo_1, Testigo_2, Coordinador) and their fields.

```
`const definicionsobre = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
  definicionsobre.templateId = Id_Plantilla;

let arraytabscandidato = [
        docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
          tabLabel: "iniciales_candidato",
          value: arrayCR[4],
        }),

        docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
          tabLabel: "domicilio_candidato",
          value: arrayCR[5],
        }),

        docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
          tabLabel: "telefono_candidato",
          value: arrayCR[7],
        }),
      ];

let tabscandidato = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({textTabs: arraytabscandidato});

      candidatoRol = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
        recipientId: arrayCR[1]
        name: arrayCR[2],
        email: arrayCR[3],
        clientUserId: 1001,
        routingOrder: 1,
        tabs: tabscandidato,
        roleName: "Candidato",
      });

let arraytabstestigo1 = [
    docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: "domicilio_t1",
      value: dataT1[3],
    }),

    docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: "relacion_t1",
        value: dataT1[4],
    }),

    docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: "telefono_t1",
        value: dataT1[5],
    }),
  ];

  let tabstestigo1 = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({textTabs:arraytabstestigo1});

  let testigo1Rol = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    recipientId: dataT1[0],
    name: dataT1[1],
    email: dataT1[2],
    clientUserId: 1001,
    routingOrder: 2,
    tabs: tabstestigo1,
    roleName: "Testigo_1",
  });


  let tabstestigo2 = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    textTabs: [
      docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        tabLabel: "domicilio_t2",
        value: dataT2[3],
      }),
      docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        tabLabel: "relacion_t2",
        value: dataT2[4],
      }),
      docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
        tabLabel: "telefono_t2",
        value: dataT2[5],
      }),
    ],
  });

  let testigo2Rol = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    recipientId: dataT2[0],
    name: dataT2[1],
    email: dataT2[2],
    clientUserId: 1001,
    routingOrder: 3,
    tabs: tabstestigo2,
    roleName: "Testigo_2",
  });

  let coordinadorRol = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    recipientId: arrayCoordi[0],
    name: arrayCoordi[1],
    email: arrayCoordi[2],
    clientUserId: 1001,
    routingOrder: 4,
    roleName: "Coordinador",
  });

  definicionsobre.templateRoles = [
    candidatoRol,
    testigo1Rol,
    testigo2Rol,
    coordinadorRol,
  ];

  definicionsobre.status = "sent";`
```

this appears for the second, third and fourth recipient:

[image: this appears for the second, third and fourth recipient]

I get this information from the envelope

```
{
    "agents": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1",
    "editors": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "notaries": [],
    "recipientCount": "4",
    "seals": [],
    "signers": [
        {
            "clientUserId": "1001",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "email": "x@x.com",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "name": "Wilfrido Rubén Ruiz Pérez",
            "note": "",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "dafceece-d81d-49f9-a4b4-34cc6a4371d9",
            "recipientType": "signer",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "roleName": "Candidato",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "sentDateTime": "2023-05-30T18:24:02.8070000Z",
            "status": "sent",
            "userId": "38609301-ed16-42cf-b82c-dcb1915f7177"
        },
        {
            "clientUserId": "1002",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "email": "x@x.com",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "name": "Yasser  Martinez Herrera",
            "recipientId": "5",
            "recipientIdGuid": "ebfb8c03-48cd-468d-baab-914d894b8f38",
            "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
            "recipientType": "signer",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "roleName": "Testigo_1",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "status": "created",
            "userId": "a2dafdc2-6a1d-42fe-a6ab-e0acd7e4fa57"
        },
        {
            "clientUserId": "1003",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "email": "x@x.com",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "name": "Brayan López Hernández",
            "recipientId": "6",
            "recipientIdGuid": "58399fe7-9f9f-45f3-9724-5cac5ff385eb",
            "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
            "recipientType": "signer",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "roleName": "Testigo_2",
            "routingOrder": "3",
            "status": "created",
            "userId": "d1623117-fe47-4655-aeb3-1f910cd933d3"
        },
        {
            "clientUserId": "1004",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "email": "x@x.com",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "name": "Adriana López Bernal",
            "recipientId": "7",
            "recipientIdGuid": "a0593aed-54fc-423d-a406-91323db9daca",
            "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
            "recipientType": "signer",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "roleName": "Coordinador",
            "routingOrder": "4",
            "status": "created",
            "userId": "7afca9a0-6958-4a8e-b9d8-0e4060b99eb0"
        }
    ],
    "witnesses": []
}
```

Comment: can you save your template as a JSON file and attach it here? want to see what your template looks like...

Comment: I share the json file hosted in git
https://github.com/BLopez97/DS_Template.git

Comment: You use the same clientUserId for all 4 roles/recipients. Try to have different values for each. Do you want them all to sign from inside your app? if not - you need not include this value.

Comment: I did it but without success.
I have analyzed the envelope's information and found this (open envelope_information file):
https://github.com/BLopez97/DS_Template.git .
everything is correct for the first recipient, but for the others this appears: "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",

Comment: can i change it to false?

Comment: Yes, that might be what is causing your recipients to be allowed to add their own tabs

Comment: do you know how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your template is just fine, but you have to change the way you create the envelope to use different `clientUserId`.
Or, you can just have it go via email. I just tested it and every one of the 4 roles have their tabs in the envelope ok.
Note too that your code has to ensure the right templateRole when you create the envelope from template, where you do this:

```
  let testigo2Rol = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    recipientId: dataT2[0],
    name: dataT2[1],
    email: dataT2[2],
    clientUserId: 1001,
    routingOrder: 3,
    tabs: tabstestigo2,
    roleName: "Testigo_2",
  });
```

roleName must match exactly what's on template, also clientUserId should be a string.

Finally, the tabs that are defined in the template are the ones showing, not the ones you are adding here. If you want more tabs - add them to the template, or you need to make another API call.